# Automatically show properties of C++ objects in Xcode debugger

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, debugging

The Xcode debug area can sometimes show a summary of the most important variables inside of an object that's in the list, without the need to expand the object to see it's individual members.

Is there a way for me to teach the debugger about my own C++ objects to do the same? Let's say I have a simple class with a single member variable:

```
class Foo
{
    int bar;
};
```

And the debug area should show something like the following:

```
aVariableOfTypeFoo = (Foo) bar=123
```

I know that some C++ objects are able to do this (for example std::vector shows it's size), but I wasn't able to figure out if this is somehow configurable, or if it's built-in in the debugger/Xcode itself.

I'm using Xcode 5.0.1

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying p or po?

Comment: @MertBuran yes, but that isn't what I was looking for. Thanks though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the summary description for a given type selecting *Edit Summary Format...* by right clicking on a variable of that type.

[image]

The format in your case is pretty simple and will look like this: `bar = {$VAR.bar}`
For more information about formats check the "Using Data Formatters" section in the [Xcode User Guide](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/Xcode_Debugging.pdf) (pages 42 & 43).

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. I didn't even assume it would be configurable in the context menu, I was expecting a configuration file or something similar.

Comment: Could you add how to do this for a pointer to an allocated array?

Comment: @Supuhstar link updated, seems like this has become legacy stuff.